Any way to force PHP FPM to read only the .user.ini file on DOCUMENT_ROOT?
It's there any way to force FPM to read only the .user.ini on the Document Root?
If we have this structure I need FPM reads only the .user.ini on root/ folder, skipping others when running the last php script.
root/.user.ini
root/other/.user.ini
root/other/another/.user.ini
root/other/another/i_m_running_this.php

I'm looking to increase security of hosted websites. The root .user.ini will have the +i (inmutable) flag set on linux.
I know if I place the config on the official PHP FPM .ini no other .user.ini can change those values.
I didn't found any way to disable the scan FPM does looking for .user.ini files starting from the directory where the script it's down to the document root.

Is there a specific reason why you can't disable .user.ini reading completely and instead only use php.ini?

Is /root/ your server's DocumentRoot folder??

The DocumentRoot usually it's /var/www/html

I prefer .user.ini because if I have several websites hosted on the same server I can use different php config on each one.

It seems like for PHP using a .user.ini is all in or all out meaning you either have to accept overrides per directory or completely disable the feature. I think you're better off just regularly deleting .user.ini files outside of roots

Yes, it seems that's the situation now. I'm trying to avoid a malware/attack adds a .user.ini to relax security measures to run malware on server. That's why I want to allow only the .user.ini on the document root. That .user.ini has the inmutable bit so no one can change it.
